# Strip specific part of query result in python

Tags: html, regex, python-3.x

I have wrote that script that uses yandex api to convert some foreign characters in english, here is the code:

```
for pre in soup.select('body'):
    pree= pre.text
    print (pree)
```

HTML is:

```
<body>
    onComplete_10([{"Alignment":"0:1-0:4 2:2-6:9 3:3-6:9","From":"zh-CHS","OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[4],"TranslatedText":"Drama Arts","TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[10]}]);
</body>
```

Returned result is(of course):

```
onComplete_10([{"Alignment":"0:1-0:4 2:2-6:9 3:3-6:9","From":"zh-CHS","OriginalTextSentenceLengths":[4],"TranslatedText":"Drama Arts","TranslatedTextSentenceLengths":[10]}]);
```

I need to get only translated text which is "Drama Arts".

**NOTE:**
I have updated my for loop. Now using regex to filter my required data but still no luck.

```
for pre in soup.select('body'):
    p = re.compile(ur'"TranslatedText":"(.*?)"')
    strr = pre.text
    pree = re.findall(p, strr)
    print (pree)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed it a bit was doing a slight mistake. Though for some reason above works with regex101.

```
for pre in soup.select('body'):
    p = re.compile(u'"TranslatedText":"(.*?)"')
    strr = pre.text
    pree = re.findall(p, strr)
    print (pree)
```

Comment: You should accept this as an answer too! Extra rep for yourself! :P